# start ipython notebook with a particular (not default) firefox profile

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I launch `ipython notebook`, I want it to launch firefox but using a particular firefox profile, which is *not* my default firefox profile.

In my `ipython` profile, I have

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'/usr/bin/firefox'
```

and that makes sure that `ipython notebook` chooses firefox. However, it chooses the default firefox profile, or else the most recently used firefox profile.

From my linux terminal, I can launch my preferred `ipython` specific firefox profile (named `ipython`) like this

```
firefox -P --no-remote ipython
```

However, doing

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'/usr/bin/firefox -P --no-remote ipython'
```

does not work at all (ipython doesn't open `firefox` at all, and skips to the another browswer'), nor does starting `ipython notebook` like so

```
ipython notebook --browser 'firefox -P --no-remote ipython'
```

which leads to and `OSError` exception.

Does anyone know of a way to launch firefox with the preferred profile?

Answer (score 0):

A little ugly but maybe better than nothing. I put the following into a shell script to launch firefox and ipython separately but at the same time i.e.

```
firefox -P ipython -no-remote

ipython notebook --no-browser
```

You will need to refresh the browser.

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses a script to start firefox with the requested profile and makes Jupyter call it.

1. Create a script in e.g. `/usr/local/bin/firefox-notebook` with the following content:

   ```
   !/bin/env sh
   firefox -P notebook $@
   ```
2. Instruct Jupyter to use that script as a browser by adding the following in your `jupyter_notebook_config.py`:

   ```
   import webbrowser
   browser = webbrowser.Mozilla('firefox-notebook')
   webbrowser.register('firefox-notebook', None, browser)
   c.NotebookApp.browser = 'firefox-notebook'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `c.NotebookApp.browser = 'firefox -P notebook --new-window %s'` to `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`. (You missed the `%s`. It will be replaced by the URL at which jupyter is served.)